# Change waiting time for new user

Tags: users

The registration of my website works by user email verification.

How can I change a waiting time of new user activation? I have many spam users that register at my website; they register and never activate the account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project [LoginToboggan](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) has a feature to auto-cancel these after a preset time.  From the LoginToboggan features list:

> Optionally have unvalidated users purged from the system at a pre-defined interval (please read the CAVEATS section of INSTALL.txt for important information on configuring this feature!).

For more ideas about how to deal with spam registrations, see: [How to deal with unverified users in Drupal?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54512/how-to-deal-with-unverified-users-in-drupal)

Comment: Thank you Gisle Hannemyr. It is exactly what I am looking for

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what @Gisle Hannemyr said, I would recommend the [spamicide](http://drupal.org/project/spamicide) module (sets hidden field that if it is filled by a bot on registration, it will not create the account) and the [re-captcha](http://drupal.org/project/recaptcha) module on your registration forms.

Comment: spamicide and recaptchas are great things. thnks